# webkit-specific css selector not working

Tags: java, css, gwt, celltable

I'm styling my GWT `CellTable` cells by overriding `getCellStyleNames` in my column definition.  Styles are working, on the most part.  I'm trying to color the background of a 4-pixel wide column, with mixed display results depending on the browser engine.  I'm expecting the following to work, but it doesn't.  I need to set the height for firefox to 0, otherwise the first row appears to have a larger height than the rest of the rows.  Any ideas?

```
.wt-tableRowGreen {
    background-color: #8DAF00;
    width: 0px;
    padding-left: 4px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    display: compact;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Setting height to 0 works fine for FF, but breaks the others.  Using browser specific selectors isn't working:

```
    -ms-height: 100%;
    -webkit-height: 100%;
    -moz-height: 0;
```

Comment: Firefox does not allow -moz-height. It's invalid.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target spesific css for Firefox, this is the solution I use:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() 
{
    /* Css for FF here */
}
```

Obviously, this is something one should generally avoid, but in some cases it's virtually impossible to get around it.